# How to find the limit

Tags: calculus

How can we find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(e^x-1-x)^2}{x(\sin x -x)}$$?

Comment: You should show your attempts, otherwise the question probably will be closed

Comment: Hint: by Taylor, you have fourth degree up and down. Four iterations of L'Hospital will work...

Comment: I didnt understand that much, like to use L'Hospital 4 times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(e^x-1-x)^2}{x(\sin x -x)} = (\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2})^2\cdot\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3}{\sin x -x} = (\frac{1}{2})^2\cdot(-6).$$

The last two limits are calculated with L'Hospital's rule.